# Website stops responding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

It stops responding after a few seconds of being idle. I have to restart it every time this happens.

I have tried putting `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` into my `applicationHost` config, but nothing changed.

The output of the console is just a bunch of

> The thread X has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I don't think this is related to `idleTimeOut` either, because the website completely stops responding; it just hangs.

`applicationHost` if anyone is interested (too large to post here):

http://pastebin.com/quVMXPHP

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: I do think you have an error in line 987... Just kidding, I do believe no one is able to help you unless you narrow down the issue.

Comment: BTW: I'm using [LeanSentry](https://www.leansentry.com/) since some weeks. It might help you, too. They have a 10-days trial period.

Comment: Yeah I figured. Thanks for replying though. Do you have any pointers on how I could narrow it down?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. If you read my post you'd understand why that doesn't work here. The entire website stops responding. It doesn't matter where I come from. This is a time issue, not an issue with my code.

Comment: What is "stops responding"? What _exactly_ happens?

Comment: It... stops responding. When you send a request to a server, the server will respond under ordinary circumstances. My server does not respond upon being sent a request by a web browser.

Comment: Pointers for narrowing down:  Install on another machine (is this already a server or localhost?).   Create a new website in IIS and move to there.  Create a whole new project/solution in VS and (when it doesn't occur) start moving code across from the old project to the new project until it starts doing it again (yes, tedious).  Add logging (eg log4net) in all key places (add an ActionFilter to log all actions and log everything in global.asax (add if you don't have one))

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's from being idle? By default, every time you stop debugging, IIS Express unloads the website, and quits entirely if there's no other websites running. You can disable this by unchecking `Enable Edit and Continue` in the project properties under the "Web" tab.

If it happens more randomly, then IIS Express may actually be crashing. Check in the notification area of the taskbar for IIS Express, make sure it's there, and (by right-clicking) ensure your web project is still loaded (in the list). If it's actually crashing, you most likely have a memory leak, infinite loop, or something similar going on somewhere in your application that's overloading the process. There's no much we can do to help you with that, without being able to examine your entire codebase. You'll just have to trace and profile until you find it.